# Where to use android:exported in Android Menifest

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, google-play-console, androidexported

When is Upload aab file on Play Console, I saw this messege "You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle which has an activity, activity alias, service or broadcast receiver with intent filter, but without 'android:exported' property set. This file can't be installed on Android 12 or higher. See: developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#exported"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.andromob.webview">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:name="freefire.cit.community.MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        tools:targetApi="m">
        <activity android:name="freefire.cit.community.Privacy_Policy" />
        <activity android:name="freefire.cit.community.AboutActivity" />

        <activity
            android:exported="true"
            android:name="freefire.cit.community.SplashActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar2"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action
                    android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:exported="true"
                    android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="freefire.cit.community.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="@string/admob_app_id" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AD_MANAGER_APP"
            android:value="true" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Please Check this Menifest File and Help me

I want to Fix this error to Upload aab file on Google Play Console. "You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle which has an activity, activity alias, service or broadcast receiver with intent filter, but without 'android:exported' property set. This file can't be installed on Android 12 or higher. See: developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#exported
"

Comment: Have you read the docs that are linked in the error?

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.andromob.webview">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:name="freefire.cit.community.MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        tools:targetApi="m">
        <activity android:name="freefire.cit.community.Privacy_Policy" 
android:exported="false"/>
        <activity android:name="freefire.cit.community.AboutActivity"
android:exported="false" />

        <activity
            android:exported="true"
            android:name="freefire.cit.community.SplashActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar2"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action
                    android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:exported="true"
                    android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="freefire.cit.community.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation"
    android:exported="false"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="@string/admob_app_id" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AD_MANAGER_APP"
            android:value="true" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
    android:exported="false"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```